# PHP hiding multiple phone numbers

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to replace phone numbers with [hidden] and show them back on click. It works great when there is only one number. But when there are more, it hides it, but the problem is that it returns the same number for both hidden fields.

```
$check ='111 111 1111 / 222 222 2222';      
preg_match('/[(]*\d{3}[)]*\s*[.\- ]*\d{3}[.\- ]*\d{4}/', $check, $phone_matches); 
echo sizeOf($phone_matches); //returns 1, why not 2??
```

Pretty much, if you can help me get the `sizeOf($phone_matches)` to show the correct amount, I should be good from there!

EDIT:

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeOf($phone_matches[0]); $i++){
    $check = preg_replace('/[(]*\d{3}[)]*\s*[.\- ]*\d{3}[.\- ]*\d{4}/', '<span class="hide">'.$phone_matches[0][$i].'</span><span class="show">show phone</span>', $check);
}

 echo $check;
```

Comment: Try `preg_match_all`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `preg_match_all`, not `preg_match`

```
preg_match_all('/[(]*\d{3}[)]*\s*[.\- ]*\d{3}[.\- ]*\d{4}/', $check, $phone_matches);
print_r($phone_matches);
```

But note that `sizeof($phone_matches)` will still be 1, since the array of matches is actually `$phone_matches[0]`.

To iterate through all the matches you would do:

```
foreach ($phone_matches[0] as $match) {
    //Do something with $match
}
```

But for what you're **actually** trying to accomplish, there's no need for `preg_match_all` at all. A simple one-line `preg_replace` will do the trick:

```
$check = preg_replace('/[(]*\d{3}[)]*\s*[.\- ]*\d{3}[.\- ]*\d{4}/', '<span class="hide">$0</span><span class="show">show phone</span>', $check);
```

Comment: okay. now how can i run the check for $phone_matches? When I do sizeOf($phone_matches) i get 1 still

Comment: how can I retrieve the correct amount of phones found? in this case, how can I get 2?

Comment: @user235196 `sizeof($phone_matches[0])`

Comment: please see my edit. Why is it not working? I get  Array to string conversion error

Comment: @user235196 You should be using `$phone_matches[0][$i]`, not `$phone_matches[$i]`

Comment: I tried the foreach and the [0][$i], it works when I just echo it but inside the span, it only takes the last ph #. Please see my edit above

Comment: @user235196 See my latest edit. Just forget `preg_match_all` and looping and just use that one line.

Comment: As a side note: how sure are you the phonenumbers are all in the `xxx xxx xxxx` format? There are many notations ([E.164](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) being one of them) like `+15415551111`, `(541) 555-1111`, `541 555 1111` etc. etc.